# Mysql query to display name from a to p range

Tags: mysql

I need to display the name of the person between a to p in mysql. How can I display the name from a to p. Please help me out how can I display it. I want to display the name of employee where name starts from A-P and a-p. Here is the query.

```
Select * from emp where name LIKE '[A-P]%';
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query

```
Select * from emp where name REGEXP '^[A-P|a-p]'
```